# Java return article base of the supply id

Tags: java

I am trying to return an article if it exists, but I am not sure how to go about doing it. The method articlebyid is supplied with an article id, it then checked if the article exists. if the article exists I want the return that article.

```java
public static Article articleById(int id, Connection conn) throws SQLException {

  try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM mytestarticles  WHERE artid = ?")) {
    stmt.setInt(1, id);

    try (ResultSet resultset = stmt.executeQuery()) {

      if (!(resultset == null)) {
        // i want to return the article here if it exist                   

      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Do you want help regarding how to construct Article object from ResultSet?

Comment: yes i need help returning the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you construct your custom object from from a ResultSet:

```java
if (!(resultset == null)) {
  Article article = new Article();      
  article.setArticleId(resultset.getString("Id"));
  article.setArticleName(resultset.getString("Name"));
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks how to i pass the return article to the jsp  i did something like try (Connection conn = DBConnectionUtils.getConnectionFromSrcFolder("connection.properties")) {
            Article articleid=ArticleDAO.articleById(id,conn);
            req.setAttribute("articlebyid",articleid);
         

            req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/content-page.jsp").forward(req,resp);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("error "+ e.getSQLState());

        }

Comment: i test print out the return article, i can see there is data in it. however when i pass it to jsp the article doesn't sisplay anything

Comment: There appears to be a lot going on in your JSP. Please write a separate question with what you are passing to JSP, proper codes and logs. That would help us a lot to help you.